# remove additional lines in FactoryBot to create json output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

This is my factory

```
 FactoryBot.define do
    factory :test do
          p_json {test_json}   
    end
    factory :test_json, class: OpenStruct do
        skip_create
        id "ff28c864e6008a05d918384bbd6adca7"
    end
 end
```

It outputs the result as

```
      :p_json => --- !ruby/object:OpenStruct
      table:
         :id: ff28c864e6008a05d918384bbd6adca7
      modifiable: true
```

Instead I want the output as a serialized hash like

```
     :p_json =>
          ---
        test_.pdf: 
          :id: 4232a9d03736e11b5f2841ac1e978873
```

How do I achieve this? TIA